# Genymotion unable to start the virtual device opengl error

Tags: virtual-machine, genymotion

I try to start a virtual device by Genymotion. But I get the error:

```
Unable to start the virtual device
To start virtual devices, make sure thet your video card supports OpenGL 2.0 and update the drivers.
Details: Failed to create framebuffer image (error: 15)
If possible, update your vido card drivers.
```

As advised at Stackoverflow I have tried to update my video card drivers. But it did not help.

I have suggested that this was due to the fact that I replaced `opengl32.dll` file in `SysWOW64` directory. I replaced it during copy to this folder `glut32.dll`, `glu32.dll` and `glut.dll` files.

How to resolve the problem?

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.

I have asked for another copy of `opengl32.dll` from my friend's computer `SysWOW64` and put it in my `SysWOW64` directory.